# Manipulating entity framework to eliminate round trips to the database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.1

Let's say I have the following bit of code (which I know could be **easily** modified to perform better, but it illustrates what I want to do)

```
List<Query> l = new List<Query>; 
// Query is a class that doesn't exist, it represents an EF operation

foreach (var x in Xs)
{
  Query o = { context.someEntity.Where(s=>s.Id==x.Id).First();} 
  // It wouldn't execute it, this is pseudo code for delegate/anonymous function
  l.Add(o)
}
```

Then send this list of Query to EF, and have it optimize so that it does the least amount of round trips possible. Let's call it BatchOptimizeAndRun; you would say

```
var results = BatchOptimizeAndRun(l);
```

And knowing what it knows from the schema it would reduce the overall query to an optimal version and execute that and place the read results in an array.

I hope I've described what I'm looking for accurately and more importantly that it exists.
And if I sound like a rambling mad man, let's pretend this question never existed.

Comment: My advice is to not attempt to bend EF to your will.  Leverage it where you can, circumvent it where you can't.  Many times when people do this they end up with a mess of hard to maintain code, and they could have created some dynamic, parameterized queries using straight ado.net in less time anyway.  If there is a feature in EF to directly address this then you should obviously use it, but otherwise I would say do it a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to echo Mr. Moore's advice, as I too have spent far too long constructing a linq-to-entities query of monolithic proportions only to find that I could have made a stored procedure in less time that was easier to read and faster to execute. That being said in your example...

```
List<int> ids = Xs.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
var results = context.someEntity.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();
```

I believe this will compile to something like

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    someEntity
WHERE
    Id IN (ids) --Where ids is a comma separated list of INT
```

Which will provide you with what you need.